# Lock screen removal protection

Tags: usb, screen

Is there any way to protect my phone from removing screen lock using lock screen removal and USB connection? If I lost my phone, I wouldn't like someone to get into it without factory reset to see my data. I've changed default USB configuration in Developers options to "Charging", but I am not sure if it is enough.

Comment: Sorry but what is a "lock screen removal"? If the phone has been booted the lock screen can't be bypassed because it is necessary to enter the password that is used to unlock the user data encryption key (without key the user data files remain encrypted except for the few files that are not bound to the user key but to the device key because the app needs them before first login).

Comment: @Robert lock screen removals are such apps: https://geekflare.com/android-lock-screen-removal/ they can be installed on computer and remove lock screen when you connect your phone via USB to computer

Comment: If I got it correctly the only tool that claims to remove a lock screen on recent phones without erasing all data is Dr. Fone. If you want to protect yourself against this tool buy a phone that is not supported by this tool. Other counter measures against such lock removal tools can only be done by the device manufacturer (-> firmware update).

Comment: @Robert I think that Dr. Fone also erases all data https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-HIduBZ6WTc so in conclusion - these apps suck

Comment: According to the article you have linked it is the only tool that can do it without erasing data but may be only for a few devices.

Comment: @Robert yes that is true. Fortunately I didn't find my phone on a list of devices for this app. It is dedicated for some models of LG and Samsung

Comment: Dr. Fone is scam. just try any tool you find, you will notice your device is secure, even against bruteforcing